# Disable options using data type attribute values in select2 V4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to disable the options using `data-type` attribute defined for each option in select2.

It doesn't work. Moreover, I'm getting this error in the change event handler:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowID' of null

The objective is to disable options in the other selects which coincide with current selected option like in the following picture:

[image]

```js
$('.employee-dropdown').select2();
$(".employee-dropdown").change(function() {

  $('.employee-dropdown option').prop('disabled', false);

  // loop each select and set the selected value to disabled in all other selects
  $('.employee-dropdown').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $('.employee-dropdown').not($this).find('option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).data('type') != '0') {

        if ($(this).data('type') == $this.data('type')) {
          $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
      }

    });

  });
  $('.employee-dropdown').select2("destroy").select2();

});
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: lightcoral !important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
 <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
 <option data-type="employee138" value="138" selected="selected">Edwin Warmer </option>
 <option data-type="employee108" value="108">Andrew Hopper </option>
 <option data-type="employee109" value="109">Andrew Moores </option>
 <option data-type="employee112" value="98">Anthony Haldron </option>
 <option data-type="employee116" value="116">Ben Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee120" value="120">Chris Gough </option>
 <option data-type="employee130" value="130">David Johnson </option>
 <option data-type="employee133" value="133">David Waterfield </option>
 <option data-type="employee143" value="143">Gary Ward </option>
 <option data-type="employee145" value="145">Gavin Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee161" value="161">John Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee171" value="171">Keith Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee176" value="176">Kevin Rose </option>
 <option data-type="employee177" value="177">Kevin Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee178" value="178">Kevin Wilcox </option>
 <option data-type="employee189" value="189">Michael Cook </option>
 <option data-type="employee195" value="195">Oliver Franklin </option>
 <option data-type="employee203" value="203">Phillip Westwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee197" value="197">Paul Davis </option>
 <option data-type="employee222" value="222">William Brophy </option>
 <option data-type="employee219" value="219">Stuart Smith </option>
 <option data-type="employee205" value="205">Rob Shorters </option>
 <option data-type="employee204" value="204">Richard Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee224" value="224">Nathan Barlow </option>
 <option data-type="employee167" value="167">Joseph Bates </option>
 <option data-type="employee227" value="227">Simon Wood </option>
 <option data-type="employee147" value="147">Geoff Hall </option>
 <option data-type="employee140" value="140">Gary Dudley </option>
 <option data-type="employee142" value="142">Gary Parkes </option>
 <option data-type="employee141" value="141">Gary Farmer </option>
 <option data-type="employee123" value="123">Christopher Yarranton </option>
 <option data-type="employee146" value="146">Gavin Williams </option>
 <option data-type="employee148" value="148">George Woodhoods </option>
 <option data-type="employee152" value="152">Ian Attwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee160" value="160">Jason Mills </option>
 <option data-type="employee166" value="166">John Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee174" value="174">Kevin Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee181" value="181">Lee Hampson </option>
 <option data-type="employee190" value="190">Michael Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee193" value="193">Neil Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee194" value="194">Nick Webb </option>
 <option data-type="employee202" value="202">Phil Clayton </option>
 <option data-type="employee217" value="217">Stewart Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee215" value="215">Stephen Jarvis </option>
 <option data-type="employee210" value="210">Shaun Smith </option>
 <option data-type="employee207" value="207">Robert Jeapes </option>
 <option data-type="employee158" value="158">Jason Bowen </option>
 <option data-type="employee114" value="114">Barry Arrowsmith </option>
</select>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
 <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
 <option data-type="employee108" value="108">Andrew Hopper </option>
 <option data-type="employee112" value="112">Anthony Haldron </option>
 <option data-type="employee120" value="120" selected="selected">Chris Gough </option>
 <option data-type="employee139" value="139">Gary Baggott </option>
 <option data-type="employee141" value="141">Gary Farmer </option>
 <option data-type="employee145" value="145">Gavin Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee152" value="152">Ian Attwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee154" value="154">Ivan McGarry </option>
 <option data-type="employee159" value="159">Jason Law </option>
 <option data-type="employee162" value="162">John Bowen </option>
 <option data-type="employee176" value="176">Kevin Rose </option>
 <option data-type="employee178" value="178">Kevin Wilcox </option>
 <option data-type="employee185" value="185">Mark Hall </option>
 <option data-type="employee189" value="189">Michael Cook </option>
 <option data-type="employee190" value="190">Michael Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee203" value="203">Phillip Westwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee197" value="197">Paul Davis </option>
 <option data-type="employee219" value="219">Stuart Smith </option>
 <option data-type="employee217" value="217">Stewart Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee216" value="216">Steven Lindsay </option>
 <option data-type="employee208" value="208">Scott Curtis </option>
 <option data-type="employee207" value="207">Robert Jeapes </option>
 <option data-type="employee158" value="158">Jason Bowen </option>
 <option data-type="employee224" value="224">Nathan Barlow </option>
 <option data-type="employee225" value="225">Mat Davis </option>
 <option data-type="employee226" value="226">Wesley Middleton </option>
 <option data-type="employee228" value="228">Connor Demachawski </option>
 <option data-type="employee230" value="230">Nathan Mercy </option>
 <option data-type="employee147" value="147">Geoff Hall </option>
 <option data-type="employee114" value="114">Barry Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee214" value="214">Stephen Evans </option>
 <option data-type="employee138" value="138">Edwin Warmer </option>
 <option data-type="employee116" value="116">Ben Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee130" value="130">David Johnson </option>
 <option data-type="employee133" value="133">David Waterfield </option>
 <option data-type="employee140" value="140">Gary Dudley </option>
 <option data-type="employee142" value="142">Gary Parkes </option>
 <option data-type="employee123" value="123">Christopher Yarranton </option>
 <option data-type="employee146" value="146">Gavin Williams </option>
 <option data-type="employee148" value="148">George Woodhoods </option>
 <option data-type="employee160" value="160">Jason Mills </option>
 <option data-type="employee161" value="161">John Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee166" value="166">John Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee174" value="174">Kevin Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee177" value="177">Kevin Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee181" value="181">Lee Hampson </option>
 <option data-type="employee193" value="193">Neil Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee194" value="194">Nick Webb </option>
 <option data-type="employee202" value="202">Phil Clayton </option>
 <option data-type="employee222" value="222">William Brophy </option>
 <option data-type="employee215" value="215">Stephen Jarvis </option>
 <option data-type="employee210" value="210">Shaun Smith </option>
 <option data-type="employee167" value="167">Joseph Bates </option>
</select>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
 <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
 <option data-type="employee179" value="179">Kyle Halford </option>
 <option data-type="employee138" value="138">Edwin Warmer </option>
 <option data-type="employee108" value="108">Andrew Hopper </option>
 <option data-type="employee109" value="109">Andrew Moores </option>
 <option data-type="employee110" value="110">Andrew Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee112" value="112">Anthony Haldron </option>
 <option data-type="employee115" value="115">Ben Downing </option>
 <option data-type="employee116" value="116">Ben Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee118" value="118">Carl Cox </option>
 <option data-type="employee120" value="120">Chris Gough </option>
 <option data-type="employee126" value="126">Daniel Eastwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee129" value="129">David Hamblett </option>
 <option data-type="employee130" value="130">David Johnson </option>
 <option data-type="employee131" value="131">David Mallin </option>
 <option data-type="employee133" value="133">David Waterfield </option>
 <option data-type="employee139" value="139">Gary Baggott </option>
 <option data-type="employee140" value="140">Gary Dudley </option>
 <option data-type="employee142" value="142">Gary Parkes </option>
 <option data-type="employee143" value="143">Gary Ward </option>
 <option data-type="employee141" value="141">Gary Farmer </option>
 <option data-type="employee123" value="123">Christopher Yarranton </option>
 <option data-type="employee145" value="145">Gavin Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee146" value="146">Gavin Williams </option>
 <option data-type="employee148" value="148">George Woodhoods </option>
 <option data-type="employee152" value="152">Ian Attwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee154" value="154">Ivan McGarry </option>
 <option data-type="employee160" value="160">Jason Mills </option>
 <option data-type="employee161" value="161">John Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee162" value="162">John Bowen </option>
 <option data-type="employee166" value="166">John Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee168" value="168">Joshua Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee171" value="171">Keith Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee174" value="174">Kevin Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee176" value="176">Kevin Rose </option>
 <option data-type="employee177" value="177">Kevin Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee178" value="178">Kevin Wilcox </option>
 <option data-type="employee181" value="181">Lee Hampson </option>
 <option data-type="employee185" value="185">Mark Hall </option>
 <option data-type="employee189" value="189">Michael Cook </option>
 <option data-type="employee190" value="190">Michael Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee193" value="193">Neil Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee194" value="194">Nick Webb </option>
 <option data-type="employee195" value="195">Oliver Franklin </option>
 <option data-type="employee203" value="203">Phillip Westwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee202" value="202">Phil Clayton </option>
 <option data-type="employee197" value="197">Paul Davis </option>
 <option data-type="employee222" value="222">William Brophy </option>
 <option data-type="employee220" value="220">Tom Downing </option>
 <option data-type="employee219" value="219">Stuart Smith </option>
 <option data-type="employee217" value="217">Stewart Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee216" value="216">Steven Lindsay </option>
 <option data-type="employee215" value="215">Stephen Jarvis </option>
 <option data-type="employee211" value="211">Simon McGarry </option>
 <option data-type="employee210" value="210">Shaun Smith </option>
 <option data-type="employee208" value="208">Scott Curtis </option>
 <option data-type="employee207" value="207">Robert Jeapes </option>
 <option data-type="employee205" value="205">Rob Shorters </option>
 <option data-type="employee204" value="204">Richard Turner </option>
 <option data-type="employee158" value="158">Jason Bowen </option>
 <option data-type="employee224" value="224">Nathan Barlow </option>
 <option data-type="employee225" value="225">Mat Davis </option>
 <option data-type="employee226" value="226">Wesley Middleton </option>
 <option data-type="employee167" value="167">Joseph Bates </option>
 <option data-type="employee172" value="172">Joseph Bache </option>
 <option data-type="employee227" value="227">Simon Wood </option>
 <option data-type="employee229" value="229">Alan Taylor </option>
 <option data-type="employee230" value="230">Nathan Mercy </option>
 <option data-type="employee147" value="147">Geoff Hall </option>
 <option data-type="employee231" value="231">Jimmy Robinson </option>
 <option data-type="employee163" value="163">John Leitch </option>
 <option data-type="employee124" value="124">Clive Jones </option>
 <option data-type="employee113" value="113">Arron Kwiatek </option>
 <option data-type="employee114" value="114">Barry Arrowsmith </option>
 <option data-type="employee164" value="164">John Mucklow </option>
 <option data-type="employee232" value="232">Scott Westwood </option>
 <option data-type="employee237" value="237">Steve Probert </option>
 <option data-type="employee238" value="238">Daniel Benjamin </option>
 <option data-type="employee214" value="214">Stephen Evans </option>
</select>
<p>
  &nbsp;
</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
 <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType97" value="97">WM65 ZLY (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType98" value="98">WM65 ZLZ (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType99" value="99">BV15 ZGB (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType100" value="100">BV15 ZFX (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType101" value="101">BV15 ZFY (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType102" value="102">BV15 ZGA (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType103" value="103">BV15 ZFZ (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType104" value="104">EX67 WVF (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType105" value="105">EX67 WRT (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType106" value="106">BV15 ZPH (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType107" value="107">BV15 ZPF (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType108" value="108">BV15 ZPG (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType109" value="109">BV15 ZPJ (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType110" value="110">BV15 ZPK (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType111" value="111">EN17 NDJ (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType133" value="133">YT57 WXJ (Welfare Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType134" value="134">YS08 LPU (Welfare Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType135" value="135">MA61 FEF (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType136" value="136">MW61 BDF (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType137" value="137">WT15 AEW (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType138" value="138">WT15 AEU (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType139" value="139">WT15 AEV (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType140" value="140">WT15 AEO (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType141" value="141">WT15 AEP (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType142" value="142">WR65 SVV (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType143" value="143">WT15 AEX (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType144" value="144">WR65 JTX (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType145" value="145">BU13 WLN (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType146" value="146">BK13 WFA (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType147" value="147">EX67 WPN (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType148" value="148">YF10 DZD (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType149" value="149">YA10 CLO (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType150" value="150">WU16 ZXR (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType151" value="151">WM65 ZST (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType152" value="152">YC11 OUJ (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType153" value="153">WM65 ZLX (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType154" value="154">WU16 ZXP (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType155" value="155">EX67 WRN (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType167" value="167">Plant Trailer (Plant Trailer)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType168" value="168">EN67 TCU (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType169" value="169">EN67 TCX (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType170" value="170">EN67 TCV (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType171" value="171">MC04 SON (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType172" value="172">BD15 ZGY (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType173" value="173">BL13 OYJ (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType174" value="174">F8 MAC (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType175" value="175">WM66 KTK (Fitter's Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType176" value="176">YB11 VWG (Fitter's Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType177" value="177">YH60 EKK (Fitter's Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType178" value="178">PK60 EZN (Fitter's Van)</option>
</select>
<p>
  &nbsp;</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
 <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType97" value="97" selected="selected">WM65 ZLY (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType98" value="98">WM65 ZLZ (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType99" value="99">BV15 ZGB (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType100" value="100">BV15 ZFX (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType101" value="101">BV15 ZFY (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType102" value="102">BV15 ZGA (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType103" value="103">BV15 ZFZ (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType104" value="104">EX67 WVF (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType105" value="105">EX67 WRT (Pickup)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType106" value="106">BV15 ZPH (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType107" value="107">BV15 ZPF (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType108" value="108">BV15 ZPG (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType109" value="109">BV15 ZPJ (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType110" value="110">BV15 ZPK (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType111" value="111">EN17 NDJ (Crewbus)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType133" value="133">YT57 WXJ (Welfare Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType134" value="134">YS08 LPU (Welfare Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType135" value="135">MA61 FEF (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType136" value="136">MW61 BDF (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType137" value="137">WT15 AEW (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType138" value="138">WT15 AEU (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType139" value="139">WT15 AEV (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType140" value="140">WT15 AEO (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType141" value="141">WT15 AEP (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType142" value="142">WR65 SVV (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType143" value="143">WT15 AEX (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType144" value="144">WR65 JTX (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType145" value="145">BU13 WLN (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType146" value="146">BK13 WFA (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType147" value="147">EX67 WPN (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType148" value="148">YF10 DZD (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType149" value="149">YA10 CLO (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType150" value="150">WU16 ZXR (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType151" value="151">WM65 ZST (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType152" value="152">YC11 OUJ (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType153" value="153">WM65 ZLX (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType154" value="154">WU16 ZXP (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType155" value="155">EX67 WRN (Planer Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType167" value="167">Plant Trailer (Plant Trailer)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType168" value="168">EN67 TCU (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType169" value="169">EN67 TCX (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType170" value="170">EN67 TCV (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType171" value="171">MC04 SON (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType172" value="172">BD15 ZGY (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType173" value="173">BL13 OYJ (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType174" value="174">F8 MAC (Small Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType175" value="175">WM66 KTK (Fitter's Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType176" value="176">YB11 VWG (Fitter's Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType177" value="177">YH60 EKK (Fitter's Van)</option>
 <option data-type="vanAssetType178" value="178">PK60 EZN (Fitter's Van)</option>
</select>
```

[fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/hgd9jtqv/)

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Check this option is correct in first select :<option data-type="employee112" value="98">Anthony Haldron</option>

Comment: @Jalin : Sorry, I did not get you what you're referring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowID' of null

That error derives from your way to refresh select2 (refresh changed since V4):

```
$('.employee-dropdown').select2("destroy").select2();
```

Because you use the default **SelectAdapter** you need to act on each option data attribute. You need to get for each option:

```
$(this).data().data
```

And for this set, according to the code:

```
optData.disabled = false;
optData.element.disabled = false;
```

And for updating each select2 it's enough:

```
$(this).trigger('change.select2');
```

In order to start everything at time of change handler definition it's enough to trigger the change event for the first select.

```js
$('.employee-dropdown').select2();

$(".employee-dropdown").on('change', function (e) {
    $('.employee-dropdown').each(function(idx, ele) {
        // remove disable attribute.....
        $(ele).find('option').each(function(idx, ele) {
            $(this).removeProp('disabled');
            var optData = $(this).data().data;
            if (optData != undefined) {
                optData.disabled = false;
                optData.element.disabled = false;
            }
        });
        // get selected values, not for current...
        var currSelOptionType = $('.employee-dropdown').not($(ele)).find(':selected').map(function (idx, ele) {
            if ($(ele).data('type') != 0) {
                return $(ele).data('type');
            }
        }).get();
        // ...and for each not selected option.... disable....
        $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').filter(function (idx, ele) {
            if (currSelOptionType.indexOf($(ele).data('type')) != -1) {
                return currSelOptionType.indexOf($(ele).data('type')) != -1;
            }
        }).each(function(idx, ele) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            var optData = $(this).data().data;
            if (optData != undefined) {
                optData.disabled = true;
                optData.element.disabled = true;
            }
        });
        $(this).trigger('change.select2');
    });
}).first().trigger('change');
```

```css
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-disabled=true] {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: lightcoral !important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>

<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
    <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
    <option data-type="employee138" value="138" selected="selected">Edwin Warmer</option>
    <option data-type="employee108" value="108">Andrew Hopper</option>
    <option data-type="employee109" value="109">Andrew Moores</option>
    <option data-type="employee112" value="98">Anthony Haldron</option>
    <option data-type="employee116" value="116">Ben Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee120" value="120">Chris Gough</option>
    <option data-type="employee130" value="130">David Johnson</option>
    <option data-type="employee133" value="133">David Waterfield</option>
    <option data-type="employee143" value="143">Gary Ward</option>
    <option data-type="employee145" value="145">Gavin Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee161" value="161">John Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee171" value="171">Keith Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee176" value="176">Kevin Rose</option>
    <option data-type="employee177" value="177">Kevin Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee178" value="178">Kevin Wilcox</option>
    <option data-type="employee189" value="189">Michael Cook</option>
    <option data-type="employee195" value="195">Oliver Franklin</option>
    <option data-type="employee203" value="203">Phillip Westwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee197" value="197">Paul Davis</option>
    <option data-type="employee222" value="222">William Brophy</option>
    <option data-type="employee219" value="219">Stuart Smith</option>
    <option data-type="employee205" value="205">Rob Shorters</option>
    <option data-type="employee204" value="204">Richard Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee224" value="224">Nathan Barlow</option>
    <option data-type="employee167" value="167">Joseph Bates</option>
    <option data-type="employee227" value="227">Simon Wood</option>
    <option data-type="employee147" value="147">Geoff Hall</option>
    <option data-type="employee140" value="140">Gary Dudley</option>
    <option data-type="employee142" value="142">Gary Parkes</option>
    <option data-type="employee141" value="141">Gary Farmer</option>
    <option data-type="employee123" value="123">Christopher Yarranton</option>
    <option data-type="employee146" value="146">Gavin Williams</option>
    <option data-type="employee148" value="148">George Woodhoods</option>
    <option data-type="employee152" value="152">Ian Attwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee160" value="160">Jason Mills</option>
    <option data-type="employee166" value="166">John Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee174" value="174">Kevin Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee181" value="181">Lee Hampson</option>
    <option data-type="employee190" value="190">Michael Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee193" value="193">Neil Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee194" value="194">Nick Webb</option>
    <option data-type="employee202" value="202">Phil Clayton</option>
    <option data-type="employee217" value="217">Stewart Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee215" value="215">Stephen Jarvis</option>
    <option data-type="employee210" value="210">Shaun Smith</option>
    <option data-type="employee207" value="207">Robert Jeapes</option>
    <option data-type="employee158" value="158">Jason Bowen</option>
    <option data-type="employee114" value="114">Barry Arrowsmith</option>
</select>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
    <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
    <option data-type="employee108" value="108">Andrew Hopper</option>
    <option data-type="employee112" value="112">Anthony Haldron</option>
    <option data-type="employee120" value="120" selected="selected">Chris Gough</option>
    <option data-type="employee139" value="139">Gary Baggott</option>
    <option data-type="employee141" value="141">Gary Farmer</option>
    <option data-type="employee145" value="145">Gavin Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee152" value="152">Ian Attwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee154" value="154">Ivan McGarry</option>
    <option data-type="employee159" value="159">Jason Law</option>
    <option data-type="employee162" value="162">John Bowen</option>
    <option data-type="employee176" value="176">Kevin Rose</option>
    <option data-type="employee178" value="178">Kevin Wilcox</option>
    <option data-type="employee185" value="185">Mark Hall</option>
    <option data-type="employee189" value="189">Michael Cook</option>
    <option data-type="employee190" value="190">Michael Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee203" value="203">Phillip Westwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee197" value="197">Paul Davis</option>
    <option data-type="employee219" value="219">Stuart Smith</option>
    <option data-type="employee217" value="217">Stewart Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee216" value="216">Steven Lindsay</option>
    <option data-type="employee208" value="208">Scott Curtis</option>
    <option data-type="employee207" value="207">Robert Jeapes</option>
    <option data-type="employee158" value="158">Jason Bowen</option>
    <option data-type="employee224" value="224">Nathan Barlow</option>
    <option data-type="employee225" value="225">Mat Davis</option>
    <option data-type="employee226" value="226">Wesley Middleton</option>
    <option data-type="employee228" value="228">Connor Demachawski</option>
    <option data-type="employee230" value="230">Nathan Mercy</option>
    <option data-type="employee147" value="147">Geoff Hall</option>
    <option data-type="employee114" value="114">Barry Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee214" value="214">Stephen Evans</option>
    <option data-type="employee138" value="138">Edwin Warmer</option>
    <option data-type="employee116" value="116">Ben Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee130" value="130">David Johnson</option>
    <option data-type="employee133" value="133">David Waterfield</option>
    <option data-type="employee140" value="140">Gary Dudley</option>
    <option data-type="employee142" value="142">Gary Parkes</option>
    <option data-type="employee123" value="123">Christopher Yarranton</option>
    <option data-type="employee146" value="146">Gavin Williams</option>
    <option data-type="employee148" value="148">George Woodhoods</option>
    <option data-type="employee160" value="160">Jason Mills</option>
    <option data-type="employee161" value="161">John Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee166" value="166">John Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee174" value="174">Kevin Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee177" value="177">Kevin Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee181" value="181">Lee Hampson</option>
    <option data-type="employee193" value="193">Neil Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee194" value="194">Nick Webb</option>
    <option data-type="employee202" value="202">Phil Clayton</option>
    <option data-type="employee222" value="222">William Brophy</option>
    <option data-type="employee215" value="215">Stephen Jarvis</option>
    <option data-type="employee210" value="210">Shaun Smith</option>
    <option data-type="employee167" value="167">Joseph Bates</option>
</select>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
    <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
    <option data-type="employee179" value="179">Kyle Halford</option>
    <option data-type="employee138" value="138">Edwin Warmer</option>
    <option data-type="employee108" value="108">Andrew Hopper</option>
    <option data-type="employee109" value="109">Andrew Moores</option>
    <option data-type="employee110" value="110">Andrew Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee112" value="112">Anthony Haldron</option>
    <option data-type="employee115" value="115">Ben Downing</option>
    <option data-type="employee116" value="116">Ben Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee118" value="118">Carl Cox</option>
    <option data-type="employee120" value="120">Chris Gough</option>
    <option data-type="employee126" value="126">Daniel Eastwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee129" value="129">David Hamblett</option>
    <option data-type="employee130" value="130">David Johnson</option>
    <option data-type="employee131" value="131">David Mallin</option>
    <option data-type="employee133" value="133">David Waterfield</option>
    <option data-type="employee139" value="139">Gary Baggott</option>
    <option data-type="employee140" value="140">Gary Dudley</option>
    <option data-type="employee142" value="142">Gary Parkes</option>
    <option data-type="employee143" value="143">Gary Ward</option>
    <option data-type="employee141" value="141">Gary Farmer</option>
    <option data-type="employee123" value="123">Christopher Yarranton</option>
    <option data-type="employee145" value="145">Gavin Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee146" value="146">Gavin Williams</option>
    <option data-type="employee148" value="148">George Woodhoods</option>
    <option data-type="employee152" value="152">Ian Attwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee154" value="154">Ivan McGarry</option>
    <option data-type="employee160" value="160">Jason Mills</option>
    <option data-type="employee161" value="161">John Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee162" value="162">John Bowen</option>
    <option data-type="employee166" value="166">John Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee168" value="168">Joshua Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee171" value="171">Keith Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee174" value="174">Kevin Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee176" value="176">Kevin Rose</option>
    <option data-type="employee177" value="177">Kevin Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee178" value="178">Kevin Wilcox</option>
    <option data-type="employee181" value="181">Lee Hampson</option>
    <option data-type="employee185" value="185">Mark Hall</option>
    <option data-type="employee189" value="189">Michael Cook</option>
    <option data-type="employee190" value="190">Michael Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee193" value="193">Neil Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee194" value="194">Nick Webb</option>
    <option data-type="employee195" value="195">Oliver Franklin</option>
    <option data-type="employee203" value="203">Phillip Westwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee202" value="202">Phil Clayton</option>
    <option data-type="employee197" value="197">Paul Davis</option>
    <option data-type="employee222" value="222">William Brophy</option>
    <option data-type="employee220" value="220">Tom Downing</option>
    <option data-type="employee219" value="219">Stuart Smith</option>
    <option data-type="employee217" value="217">Stewart Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee216" value="216">Steven Lindsay</option>
    <option data-type="employee215" value="215">Stephen Jarvis</option>
    <option data-type="employee211" value="211">Simon McGarry</option>
    <option data-type="employee210" value="210">Shaun Smith</option>
    <option data-type="employee208" value="208">Scott Curtis</option>
    <option data-type="employee207" value="207">Robert Jeapes</option>
    <option data-type="employee205" value="205">Rob Shorters</option>
    <option data-type="employee204" value="204">Richard Turner</option>
    <option data-type="employee158" value="158">Jason Bowen</option>
    <option data-type="employee224" value="224">Nathan Barlow</option>
    <option data-type="employee225" value="225">Mat Davis</option>
    <option data-type="employee226" value="226">Wesley Middleton</option>
    <option data-type="employee167" value="167">Joseph Bates</option>
    <option data-type="employee172" value="172">Joseph Bache</option>
    <option data-type="employee227" value="227">Simon Wood</option>
    <option data-type="employee229" value="229">Alan Taylor</option>
    <option data-type="employee230" value="230">Nathan Mercy</option>
    <option data-type="employee147" value="147">Geoff Hall</option>
    <option data-type="employee231" value="231">Jimmy Robinson</option>
    <option data-type="employee163" value="163">John Leitch</option>
    <option data-type="employee124" value="124">Clive Jones</option>
    <option data-type="employee113" value="113">Arron Kwiatek</option>
    <option data-type="employee114" value="114">Barry Arrowsmith</option>
    <option data-type="employee164" value="164">John Mucklow</option>
    <option data-type="employee232" value="232">Scott Westwood</option>
    <option data-type="employee237" value="237">Steve Probert</option>
    <option data-type="employee238" value="238">Daniel Benjamin</option>
    <option data-type="employee214" value="214">Stephen Evans</option>
</select>

<p>
    &nbsp;
</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
    <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType97" value="97">WM65 ZLY (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType98" value="98">WM65 ZLZ (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType99" value="99">BV15 ZGB (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType100" value="100">BV15 ZFX (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType101" value="101">BV15 ZFY (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType102" value="102">BV15 ZGA (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType103" value="103">BV15 ZFZ (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType104" value="104">EX67 WVF (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType105" value="105">EX67 WRT (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType106" value="106">BV15 ZPH (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType107" value="107">BV15 ZPF (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType108" value="108">BV15 ZPG (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType109" value="109">BV15 ZPJ (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType110" value="110">BV15 ZPK (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType111" value="111">EN17 NDJ (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType133" value="133">YT57 WXJ (Welfare Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType134" value="134">YS08 LPU (Welfare Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType135" value="135">MA61 FEF (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType136" value="136">MW61 BDF (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType137" value="137">WT15 AEW (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType138" value="138">WT15 AEU (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType139" value="139">WT15 AEV (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType140" value="140">WT15 AEO (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType141" value="141">WT15 AEP (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType142" value="142">WR65 SVV (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType143" value="143">WT15 AEX (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType144" value="144">WR65 JTX (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType145" value="145">BU13 WLN (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType146" value="146">BK13 WFA (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType147" value="147">EX67 WPN (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType148" value="148">YF10 DZD (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType149" value="149">YA10 CLO (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType150" value="150">WU16 ZXR (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType151" value="151">WM65 ZST (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType152" value="152">YC11 OUJ (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType153" value="153">WM65 ZLX (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType154" value="154">WU16 ZXP (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType155" value="155">EX67 WRN (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType167" value="167">Plant Trailer (Plant Trailer)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType168" value="168">EN67 TCU (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType169" value="169">EN67 TCX (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType170" value="170">EN67 TCV (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType171" value="171">MC04 SON (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType172" value="172">BD15 ZGY (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType173" value="173">BL13 OYJ (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType174" value="174">F8 MAC (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType175" value="175">WM66 KTK (Fitter's Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType176" value="176">YB11 VWG (Fitter's Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType177" value="177">YH60 EKK (Fitter's Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType178" value="178">PK60 EZN (Fitter's Van)</option>
</select>

<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<select name="" class="form-control employee-dropdown">
    <option data-type="0" value="">--Select --</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType97" value="97" selected="selected">WM65 ZLY (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType98" value="98">WM65 ZLZ (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType99" value="99">BV15 ZGB (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType100" value="100">BV15 ZFX (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType101" value="101">BV15 ZFY (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType102" value="102">BV15 ZGA (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType103" value="103">BV15 ZFZ (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType104" value="104">EX67 WVF (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType105" value="105">EX67 WRT (Pickup)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType106" value="106">BV15 ZPH (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType107" value="107">BV15 ZPF (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType108" value="108">BV15 ZPG (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType109" value="109">BV15 ZPJ (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType110" value="110">BV15 ZPK (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType111" value="111">EN17 NDJ (Crewbus)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType133" value="133">YT57 WXJ (Welfare Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType134" value="134">YS08 LPU (Welfare Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType135" value="135">MA61 FEF (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType136" value="136">MW61 BDF (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType137" value="137">WT15 AEW (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType138" value="138">WT15 AEU (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType139" value="139">WT15 AEV (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType140" value="140">WT15 AEO (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType141" value="141">WT15 AEP (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType142" value="142">WR65 SVV (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType143" value="143">WT15 AEX (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType144" value="144">WR65 JTX (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType145" value="145">BU13 WLN (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType146" value="146">BK13 WFA (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType147" value="147">EX67 WPN (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType148" value="148">YF10 DZD (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType149" value="149">YA10 CLO (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType150" value="150">WU16 ZXR (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType151" value="151">WM65 ZST (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType152" value="152">YC11 OUJ (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType153" value="153">WM65 ZLX (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType154" value="154">WU16 ZXP (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType155" value="155">EX67 WRN (Planer Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType167" value="167">Plant Trailer (Plant Trailer)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType168" value="168">EN67 TCU (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType169" value="169">EN67 TCX (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType170" value="170">EN67 TCV (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType171" value="171">MC04 SON (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType172" value="172">BD15 ZGY (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType173" value="173">BL13 OYJ (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType174" value="174">F8 MAC (Small Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType175" value="175">WM66 KTK (Fitter's Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType176" value="176">YB11 VWG (Fitter's Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType177" value="177">YH60 EKK (Fitter's Van)</option>
    <option data-type="vanAssetType178" value="178">PK60 EZN (Fitter's Van)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It was working fine if i use value attr from the options but I want to do the same action using data-type attributes because two sets of data but the values can be same that's why I want to do with data-type attribute values. is it possible?

Comment: I just checked, its only working for the current selected option not for already selected options.

Comment: Yes it should check all the values from the beginning and continue. Please check this screen https://prnt.sc/ktj6yw   and also is it possible to disable the options which are already selected when we open any dropdown?

Comment: Is there a way that we can strike out the text for the selected options and make them to be selected instead of disabling the options? I'm trying to add css, but its not applying :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure, I'll post this as another question.

Comment: I did, Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368407/strike-out-the-text-for-the-options-instead-of-disabling-them-select2-v4